# I am trying to get the 800.00 frequencies on a Baofeng UV-5R

Tags: uhf, baofeng, radio-programming, uv-5r

I am trying to use my Baofeng radio as a police scanner and all the frequencies are in the 800.000 frequencies. Example: I am putting 851.1500 into the “scanner”, but the Baofeng radio is not accepting it.

Comment: What are *"the 800.000 frequencies"*? Frequencies in the range 800 kHz to 900 kHz? Or in the range 800 MHz to 900 MHz? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen MHz, certainly. That's how frequencies are entered on the UV-5R, and 800MHz is a public-safety band in the US (well, the parts of it that haven't been given over to cell phones).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do that. Depending on the revision of UV-5R you have, the highest receive frequency is either 470 MHz or 520 MHz. Either way it doesn't go up to 800.